# Batch file for creating HTML pages

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2008, batch-file, dreamweaver

I have an existing website of 1100 pages. Each page has the same layout, but I need to use a template from dreamweaver to create the new pages. How can I create 1100 blank HTML pages without having to manually create them. I would like to use the layout from my new template in dreamweaver.

Comment: Are you using an existing CMS, or do you manage the pages by hand? 

If you're doing it by hand, good luck...

Comment: I am doing this by hand + there is a back end CMS that I will use... But I need to create the 1100 pages 1st with my template code.

Comment: What CMS are you using? Have you look to see if the CMS will do the templating for you? Most of them do.

Answer (score 0):

Get c# to do the same thing you would manually. That’s the best part about .NET — it can automate most Windows systems.

Pseudo-code:

```
Read your template into var a
make replacements you need to on var a into var b
write file b to where you need it
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx

Comment: I cant i dont know any of the information template names, folder names all of that is needed to do it for him if you would like it building i charge £60 an hour